# How to remove the other DE's which get installed while installing GNOME and Cinnamon?

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, gnome-classic, cinnamon

I installed Cinnamon from the terminal and Cinnamon(Software Rendering) also got installed. While installing GNOME from the terminal and GNOME Classic, GNOME Flashback(Compiz) & GNOME Flashback (Metacity) got installed. As it is I have Plasma, MATE and Budgie installed and now there's just too many options in the DE menu of lightdm... I can't even scroll down to find unity any more. So can anyone tell a proper way to selectively remove Cinnamon(Software Rendering), GNOME Classic, GNOME Flashback(Compiz) & GNOME Flashback (Metacity) without losing Cinnamon and GNOME?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
To remove both the GNOME flashback sessions all I had to do was run

sudo apt-get remove gnome-session-flashback

followed by

sudo apt-get autoremove

from the terminal. To remove GNOME Classic and Cinnamon(Software Rendering) I used [this guide](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-remove-logon-sessions-from-ubuntu-11-10/)

Here's how I did it:

From the terminal run:

cd /usr/share/xsessions

Next List all the sessions using

ls

All the DE's which show in the lightDM menu should be listed there. Now all you have to do is remove the ones you don't need using

sudo rm session-name.desktop

I wanted to remove GNOME classic and Cinnamon(Software Rendering) so I ran:

sudo rm gnome-classic.desktop

followed by:

sudo rm cinnamon2d.desktop

[image: terminal]

Proof:

[image: login-screen]

P.S:The above workaround only removes the entry and DOES NOT UNINSTALL THE PACKAGES. And if you're wondering how I got the steam login, [here's how](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-login-to-steam-big-picture-mode-in-ubuntu).